# How to prove $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ is a Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$
 denote the set of $\mathbb{C}$-valued square integrable functions on the interval [0,1]. 
Prove that $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ forms a Hilbert Space.

I believe that I can use the following steps to prove this, but I'm not sure how to write the proofs for them. What do you guys think?

a. Prove that $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ is a sub-vector of F([0,1]), the vector space of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions

b. Let <,>: $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ x $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$ denote the inner product defined by

= $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$
- in which i have to show its well-defined, linear, conjugate-symmetric, and positive definite.

c. Show that its a metric space

d. Last, show that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^2[(0,1)]$ converges.

I need help to prove (a)-(d)

Comment: Your MathJax is not correct (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Laplace transforms.

Comment: I'm trying to show that the specific laplace transformation is a Hilbert space

Comment: The Laplace transform is actually something else entirely, that also happens to use the letter $L$. In your case, you're looking at the space $\mathcal{L}^2$, which stands for the *Lebesgue* space.

Answer (score 3):

This $\mathcal L^2(0,1)$ is *not* a Hilbert space, since the inner product isn't positive-definite. You have to restrict to the quotient space wrt the equivalence relation $f\sim g\iff\mu(\{x\in(0,1): f(x)\ne g(x)\})=0$.

Comment: Can you please give an explicit example for the non-positive definiteness of the inner product?

Comment: The indicator function of any set which has null measure, e.g. $f(x)=1$ if $x=1/2 $ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere: the inner product $\langle f, f\rangle$ is zero, but $f$ isn't the zero of $\mathcal L^2(0,1)$.